# I am getting not iterable error what should i do?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm getting this error:

> bodyPartsData is not iterable TypeError: bodyPartsData is not iterable
> at fetchExercisesData (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:794:31)

the code:

```
const fetchExercisesData = async () => {
const bodyPartsData = await fetchData('https://exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com/exercises/bodyPartList',exerciseOptions);

setbodyParts(['all',...bodyPartsData]);
}

fetchExercisesData();
   
}, []);
```

What could be the solution?

I expected no error

Comment: is `bodyPartsData` an object or an array?

Comment: You can only spread an**array** into another array. So log `bodyPartsData` and see what it is

Comment: can you share the whole code file?

Answer (score 1):

I think it could look like this:
xample of how you can modify your code to handle this error:

```
const fetchExercisesData = async () => {
  const bodyPartsData = await fetchData('https://exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com/exercises/bodyPartList', exerciseOptions);

  if (Array.isArray(bodyPartsData)) {
    setbodyParts(['all', ...bodyPartsData]);
  } else {
    console.error('bodyPartsData is not an array:', bodyPartsData);
    // Handle the error or set a default value if necessary
  }
};

fetchExercisesData();
```